# How to expires session when browser is close in passport.js

Tags: node.js, passport.js, express-session, onbeforeunload

I want to expire session when the browser  is closed.

I'm using res.cookie('testlocale', 'en', { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true });

Also which event should i use in front end(onbeforeunload  or onunlod)

I'm not able to understand how to do this. I'm using handlebars in front-end

Comment: see https://github.com/expressjs/session#cookieexpires

Answer (score 0):

If you use `express-session`.
You can set `expires: false`.

> req.session.cookie
> Each session has a unique cookie object accompany it. This allows you to alter the session cookie per visitor. For example we can set req.session.cookie.expires to false to enable the cookie to remain for only the duration of the user-agent.

[From docs](https://github.com/expressjs/session#reqsessioncookie)

If you want to manually delete cookies on frontend, I think both are good fit. But I'm not sure it's good idea.